# Can a US green card applicant living in Canada apply for a US tourist visa?

Tags: immigration, canada, greencard

I recently moved to Canada. I am not Canadian and not a Canadian Permanent Resident. My brother has petitioned a green card application for me 5 years ago. My application takes more than 12 years and I was wondering if I could apply for a tourist visa to visit my brother and relatives in California.

Will my tourist visa application be an immediate rejection due to my pending green card application or I have a chance of getting a visa?

Please advise.

Comment: For completeness, what is your immigration status in Canada? What ties to Canada do you have that would enable you to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent [INA Section 214(b)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't applied for anything yet, your brother filed a petition which started a process at the end of which you may have an opportunity to apply for an immigration visa/status.

Until then you can apply for a tourist visa just like everyone else.